# using counter instead of salt for hashing

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, salt, one-time-password

I'm developing own protocol for secure message exchanging.
Each message contains the following fields: HMAC, time, salt, and message itself. HMAC is computed over all other fields using known secret key.

Protocol should protect against reply attack. On large time interval "time" record protects against replay attack (both sides should have synchronized clocks). But for protection against replay attack on short time intervals (clocks are not too accurate) I'm planning replace "salt" field with counter increasing every time, when new message is send. Receiving party will throw away messages with counter value less or equal to the previous message counter.

What I'm doing wrong?

Initial counter value can be different (I can use party identifier as initial value), but it will be known to the attacker (party identifier transmitted in unencrypted form).
(https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/what-is-a-good-enough-salt-for-a-saltedhash)

But attacker can precompute rainbow tables for counter+1, counter+2, counter+3... if I will not use really random salt?

Comment: When you say "reply attack" do you mean "replay attack?"

Comment: BTW, what is your design reason for not using a TLS (SSL) channel, which should already give you a secure way to exchange messages? Developing secure protocols correctly is challenging. Unless there is a strong reason, you should route your messages over TLS.

Comment: Protocol is designed for embedded application with very constrained RAM size and CPU power: was pretty difficult to implement Diffie-Hellman and HMAC-MD5 for PIC microcontroller. Almost impossible to implement SSL (or use some opensource implementations).

Comment: Been there… you may want to investigate the SSH protocol. There are a few commercial offerings there (PeerSec and Romsshell come to mind). DropBear is free, but is probably way too large (and I think it needs a POSIX stack). Anyway; just thinking of existing protocols. I'll think about your actual question now…

Comment: Do you have sessions, or would the counter increment infinitely? Are you also encrypting the message (with the shared secret key)?

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46131/using-counter-instead-of-salt-for-hashing)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain of your design and requirements, so some of this may be off base; hopefully some of it is also useful.

First, I'm having a little trouble understanding the attack; I'm probably just missing something. Alice sends a message to Bob that includes a counter, a payload, and an HMAC of (counter||payload). Eve intercepts and replays the message. Bob has seen that one, so he throws it away. Eve tries to compute a new message with counter+1, but she is unable to compute the HMAC for this message (since the counter is different), so Bob throws it away. As long as there is a secret available, Eve should never be able to forge a message, and replaying a message does nothing.

So what is the "known secret key?" Is this key known to the attacker? (And if it is, then he can trivially forge messages, so the HMAC isn't helpful.) Since you note that you have DH, are you using that to negotiate a key?

Assuming I'm missing the attack, thinking through the rest of your question: If you have a shared secret, why not use that to encrypt the message, or at least the time+counter? By encrypting the time and counter together, a rainbow table should be impractical.

If there is some shared secret, but you don't have the processor available to encrypt, you could still do something like MD5(secret+counter) to prevent an attacker guessing ahead (you must already have MD5 available for your HMAC-MD5).

I have attacked this problem before with no shared secret and no DH. In that case, the embedded device needed a per-device public/private keypair (ideally installed during manufacturing, but it can be computed during first power-on and stored in nonvolatile memory; randomness is hard, one option is to let the server provide a random number service; if you have any piece of unique non-public information on the chip, like a serial number, that can be used to seed your key, too. Worst case, you can use your MAC plus the time plus as much entropy as you can scrounge from the network.)

With a public/private key in place, rather than using HMAC, the device just signs its messages, sending its public key to the server in its first message. The public key becomes the identifier of the device. The nice thing about this approach is that there is no negotiation phase. The device can just start talking, and if the server has never heard of this public key, it creates a new record.

There's a small denial-of-service problem here, because attackers could fill your database with junk. The best solution to that is to generate the keys during manufacturing, and immediately insert the public keys into your database. That's impractical for some contract manufacturers. So you can resort to including a shared secret that the device can use to authenticate itself to the server the first time. That's weak, but probably sufficient for the vast majority of cases.